# Laravel RESTful route with two variables

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, routes

I am trying to make a RESTful route with two variables:

```
Route::post('trips/{trip_id}/{user_id}', [
    'as'   => 'trips.apply',
    'uses' => 'TripsController@applyForTrip'
]);
```

Controller:

```
public function applyForTrip($trip_id, $user_id)
{
    dd('I am here! Hooray!');
}
```

trigger in the view:

```
{{ HTML::linkRoute('trips.apply', 'Get on the ride!', [$trip->id, Auth::user()->id], ['class' => 'btn btn-lg btn-success']) }}
```

So, I when I fire up the route, I get `MethodNotAllowedHttpException`. So I was wondering, perhaps I am not declaring the route correctly, or smth else, but to me it seems all alright. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click on an anchor link, the browser will send a GET request to the URL referenced in the `href` attribute.  You have defined the route as a POST route in Laravel and, since Laravel can not find a GET route that matches the requested URL, you get the dreaded method not allowed exception.

Comment: So, shall I use `URL::route()` instead? Or maybe `URL::action()`?

Comment: No, you cannot do a POST request from a link on a page without extra JavaScript.  I would change your route to GET, _or_ change how the route is accessed.  What really matters is if anything on the server (API) gets changed when the route is hit as to whether it should be GET or POST

Comment: Hm... Okay, I guess I will use a `submit`, encapsulated in a `Form`. That seems like the cleanest and fastest solution...

Comment: Because the action of the route will store/update information in the database, therefore (at least to me) it makes sense that the route shout be `POST`, but not `GET`. Am I right?

Comment: You are correct. [This page](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html) is probably not linked-to nor read enough by developers, so I share it with you now.